# Custom .Net windows service not run when background "windows update" service installing updates

Tags: c#, .net

I have windows service developed using .Net framework 4.5.2, C#.
Windows service calls WebAPI using "HttpClient" after every 1min.
My custom windows service works fine even after machine restarts but as per my observation when "Windows Update" service try to install security update or any updates in background then my custom windows service not able to call WebAPI.
I checked event log also but nothing any exception or any log.

```
CameraViewModel cvm = new CameraViewModel();
                cvm.Result = base64ImgData;
                cvm.LotId = "1";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverUrl.ToString());
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<CameraViewModel>("api/ControllerName/ActionMethodName/", cvm);
                    postTask.Wait();
                    var resultt = postTask.Result;
                    Task<string> readAsync = resultt.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(readAsync.Result);
                    JToken fdate = JObject.Parse(readAsync.Result)["data"];
                    vehicleNumber = fdate.Value<string>("no");
                    //message = fdate.Value<string>("message");
                }
```

As per my observation windows service not able to call WebAPI when windows updates are installing in background.

Update Solution:

Yes now my custom windows service runs fine. 
Thanks for your support "ZorgoZ".
I followed the instructions given like,
1. Remove .Wait() method.
2. Use async/await for HttpClient request.
3. Create single instance for the HttpClient

The modified code is below:

```
    public async Task<string> GetVehicleNumber(string imgData)
    {
        string vehicleNumber = "N/A";
        CameraViewModel cvm = new CameraViewModel();
        cvm.Result = imgData;
        cvm.LotId = "1";

        string serverUrl = "ServerURL";

        try
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Client.PostAsJsonAsync(serverUrl.ToString() + "ControllerName/ActionMethodName/", cvm).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string contentt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JToken resData = JObject.Parse(contentt.Result)["data"];
                vehicleNumber = resData.Value<string>("no");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return vehicleNumber;
    }
```

Above function called from normal function like,

```
var taskLPN = Task.Run(async () => await GetVehicleLPNoIn(imgData));
vehicleNumber = task.Result;
```

Actually I have added my code in short only because this functionality have other mechanisms also.

So one thing everyone need to know is don't use .Wait() method when you are calling asynchronous API and don't create new instance of HttpClient each time whenever calling API.

Thank You!!!

Comment: You have checked the system event log or do you have any exception handling yourself? Your post does not contain any `catch` at all. You definitely should have. Nevertheless, consider two other things: 1) HttpClient is meant to be reused if the base address does not change; create it once per application and call its methods as needed even from different threads. 2) async/await is supported in framework 4.5 -use it! `.Wait()` is blocking.

Comment: An other thing: are you creating HttpClient instances frequently? If yes you are probably exhausting the socket capacity of the system. On the other hand, it can well be, that the update service has priority in such cases, even can it (I have no proof for that, but I certainly can imagine) block you from creating a new instance of HttpClient while it is doing its job. Take a look here: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ To avoid this you definitely should reuse a single httpClient instance.

Comment: "ZorgoZ" thanks for pointing out these points. I have ' try' ....' catch ' block but nothing found. As per given link I will try to create single instance for the HttpClient and will use async/await as suggested. I will update after aplying these changes.

Comment: Any progress? Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Hi @ZorgoZ please see update solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should use `HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(serverUrl.ToString() + "ControllerName/ActionMethodName/", cvm);` instead.

Comment: And also you should set `BaseAddress` to _ServerUrl_ and only `"ControllerName/ActionMethodName/..."` in the request. Not only because it is neater, but because there are things under the hood that work better this way.